# Is a Hopfield network with a continuous activation variable and a discrete time variable possible?

Tags: neural-network

I've found plenty of resources on [Hopfield networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network) that use either discrete variables for both activation level and time or continuous variables for both activation level and time. **Is it possible to construct a Hopfield neural network that uses a continuous variable for activation level and a discrete variable for time?** If it is possible, can anyone offer resources and/or tips on how to construct one in software?

Comment: I don't know, but here is the reverse: [continuous time with binary neurons](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/orponen/papers/nc2000.pdf) Orponen, P., & Šıma, J. (2000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some additional research, I think the answer is yes. It just means using a fixed timestep for the continuous-time activation equation (as described [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hopfield_network#Graded_neuron_response_and_continuous_variables)). Since this is a differential equation, implementing it in software requires implementing a numerical integration method. I recommend the [Exponential Euler Method](http://www.genesis-sim.org/BABEL/gum-tutorials/cornelis/doc/html/node9.html) as a starting point, because it's relatively simple and it's designed for differential equations of the sort that's used for the continuous Hopfield network.